# MySQL Replace Into Only Inserting Approximately 14,000 of 54,000 records from .csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've modified a PHP script to import a .csv into a table in my database. The only problem with it is that the .csv file contains ~54,000 lines, and only ~14,000 records are being inserted into my table. This is the section of code in question:

```
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";

$dbconn = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die('could not connect '     .mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('could not connect ' .mysql_error());




$lines = 1;
$queries = "";
$linearray = array();

foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {
    $lines++;
    $line = trim($line," \t");
    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);

    // escape ' character
    $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);

    /*************************************/

    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);
    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);


    $query = "replace into $dbtable values('$linemysql');";

    // I added this line to try and track entries - when run, $lines goes up to my ~54,000
    echo "Record number $lines inserted \n";

    $queries .= $query . "\n";
    @mysql_query($query);

}

@mysql_close($dbconn);
```

Can anyone see why only ~14,000 records would be inserted? I'm baffled here.

Comment: Sounds like your PHP script is hitting a timeout (by default it only runs for 60 seconds I believe.)

Comment: You maybe have failing queries. Use `mysql_query($query);` instead of `@mysql_query($query);`

Comment: Any unique or primary key duplicates you're possibly overwriting by using REPLACE instead of INSERT?

Comment: You have a number of problems here, you are manually working with CSV file instead of using something more appropriate like fgetcsv.  You are doing single inserts for each line rather than grouping them to minimize your number of queries. You are not escaping your data at all. You are using deprecated mysql extension and suppressing any error messages you might have.  You have not considered what might be the best solution of all, which is a single `LOAD DATA INFILE` query.

Answer (score 0):

File is to big and probably there is problem with timeout.

Try to insert directly form PHPmyAdmin, but I think thet you will get same problem.

Maybe to try to made a couple of files from your csv file and them insert them separately.

Good luck! :)